# Error: Unexpected module 'DatePickerModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to use **DatePickerModule** of Angular in my application.  So I have installed the package as follows: npm install ng2-datepicker-bootstrap --save

Installation was successful.  So now, I imported the **DatePickerModule** module in my AppModule as shown below:

```
import { DatePickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker-bootstrap';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    other Components......,
    DatePickerModule
  ],
  imports: [
    ........
  ],
  providers: [Service, DatePickerModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Then use the code below in my **info.component.html**.

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="model.firstDate" [viewFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY'" [modelFormat]="'YYYY-MM-DD'"  [id]="'firstDate'" [label]="'To'"></datepicker>
```

But when I run the project I got this error : 
**Error: Unexpected module 'DatePickerModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.**

I am new to Angular2 by the way.

Comment: Add it to the `imports`

Comment: Why its added in declararion,?it should be only in imports . Read documentation on npm.

Comment: ops, it should be in import. I'll try that one now.

Comment: tried that but got another error. Can't bind to 'viewFormat' since it isn't a known property of 'datepicker'. ("

Comment: try `attr.viewFormat` instead

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting your DatePickerModule in providers. Only services needs to be put in there angular create the instance of the service when the application is bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Check for missing  reference in the import statement in module.ts file.
If you have in your component:

```
import { DatePickerModule,SomeOtherModule } from 'somewhere';
```

in module.ts file you must have the same import

`import { DatePickerModule,SomeOtherModule } from 'somewhere';`

If you have only

`import { DatePickerModule } from 'somewhere';`

or you don't have the import statement
then this error will be thrown because you did not add "SomeOtherModule" to the import statement.